# Postgres choose seq scan instead of index scan during JOIN with more elements in the 'IN CLAUSE'

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 different queries with the only difference is the number of elements in the 'IN CLAUSE'.

The first query have 3 elements

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM myi_post
LEFT JOIN myi_post_hashtag ON myi_post_hashtag.post_id = myi_post.id
WHERE myi_post.id IN ('2579','2577','2575')
ORDER by myi_post.id DESC
```

It correctly uses index scan on myi_post_hashtag

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.56..44.23 rows=3 width=156) (actual time=0.009..0.018 rows=14 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan Backward using myi_post_pkey on myi_post  (cost=0.28..19.23 rows=3 width=108) (actual time=0.006..0.009 rows=3 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{2579,2577,2575}'::bigint[]))
  ->  Index Scan using myi_post_hashtag_post_id_index on myi_post_hashtag  (cost=0.28..8.32 rows=2 width=40) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=5 loops=3)
        Index Cond: (post_id = myi_post.id)
Planning time: 0.199 ms
Execution time: 0.042 ms
```

The second query has 4 elements

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM myi_post
LEFT JOIN myi_post_hashtag ON myi_post_hashtag.post_id = myi_post.id
WHERE myi_post.id IN ('2579','2577','2575','2571')
ORDER by myi_post.id DESC
```

It instead uses seq scan on myi_post_hashtag which is a lot slower

```
Sort  (cost=51.44..51.45 rows=4 width=156) (actual time=0.215..0.216 rows=16 loops=1)
  Sort Key: myi_post.id DESC
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB
  ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=24.74..51.40 rows=4 width=156) (actual time=0.198..0.207 rows=16 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (myi_post_hashtag.post_id = myi_post.id)
        ->  Seq Scan on myi_post_hashtag  (cost=0.00..23.40 rows=1240 width=40) (actual time=0.003..0.078 rows=1240 loops=1)
        ->  Hash  (cost=24.69..24.69 rows=4 width=108) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=4 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
              ->  Index Scan Backward using myi_post_pkey on myi_post  (cost=0.28..24.69 rows=4 width=108) (actual time=0.006..0.011 rows=4 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{2579,2577,2575,2571}'::bigint[]))
Planning time: 0.212 ms
Execution time: 0.246 ms
```

What could be the reason of this? Note that I've tried run VACUUM ANALYZE but nothing changes. Is there a way I could hint Postgres to always use the index?

Comment: Seems like a pretty small difference to be worrying over, especially considering the planning time add to the execution time.  Is there some context to that makes this more important than it seems?

Comment: @jjanes Our real query actually has ~20 elements in our IN CLAUSE with multiple JOINs like this causing it to be significantly slower

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does not have planner hints built-in, but there is a 3rd party extension to add them, https://github.com/ossc-db/pg_hint_plan.  I have not used it much and can't vouch for it but it does look promising as an answer to your last question.

As for the reason, I think that this mostly comes down to PostgreSQL always assuming that some substantial amount of data is going to be coming from disk. While in your case I suspect that this is not true, either because you have been testing the same queries over and over again and so the part of the data relevant to your queries is already in memory, or because all your data is in memory because to it all fits and is used often enough to accumulate there naturally.

If your data is on SSD, it would make sense to lower random_page_cost from 4 to something like 1.1 or 1.0 (i.e. the same as seq_page_cost), and I'm pretty sure this would cause it to change this query to use your preferred plan.

Even if your data is on HDD but you assume it will stay cached in memory, then it might make sense to do the same thing, but if your assumption is ever wrong, it could lead to some truly dreadful plans.  If you do go this route, you should definitely make use of [pg_prewarm.autoprewarm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgprewarm.html).